# Display the biggest width of element among other three elements inside a Div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have created a Dialog using JqueryUI. Inside that dialog I have a `<div>`, and inside that `<div>`, I have three `<button>`. "Delete", "Cancel" and "Ok". All of the three elements widths are different. I have not given the size by myself. The sizes are getting created according to the length of the word on the buttons. I want to display the max width size (in pixel) of the element among all three elements.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      dialog = $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          "Delete": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          },
          "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          },
          "Ok": function () {
          var width =  $("[aria-describedby='dialog-confirm'] .ui-dialog-   buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset > button").width();
          alert();
          }
```

I am stuck here.

Comment: You want to alert the width of the widest button upon clicking the OK button?

Comment: @j08691, yes you are right.

Comment: Can we assume that `"[aria-describedby='dialog-confirm'] .ui-dialog-   buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset > button"` is correctly targeting the buttons?

Comment: Do you need to know which button is the widest, or are you only looking for the width in pixels?

Comment: @LcSalazar, Yes it is. I have tried it.

Comment: @j08691, The widest button is visible. I want to display what the pixel of the widest button is having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the width of the widest button, you can use this:

```
dialog = $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Delete": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
            "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
            "Ok": function () {
            var widest = 0;
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonset button').each(function () {
                if ($(this).width() > widest) widest = $(this).width();
            })
            alert(widest);
        }
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5cf8dvhm/)**